# Java, double and float

Tags: java

```
double i = 100 / 3;
float j = 100 / 3;

System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(j);
```

Возвращает: 33.0

Почему не 33.3?

Comment: Где-то тут куча дубликатов про целочисленное деление

Comment: Потому, что не `double i = 100 / 3.0;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `java` деление двух целых чисел в результате вернет целое число.

По этому сначала выполняется деления `100/3` и оно равно `33`. И только потом происходит приведение к типу `double` и получается `33.0`

Для нужного вам результата можно делить так:

```
double i = 100.0 / 3;
```