# Android. Вычисления с float

Tags: java, android, float

**Имеется:**

```
float three_I_ten = 3 / 10;
```

**Производится запись в Log:**

```
Log.d("TAG_LOG", "three_I_ten = " + String.valueOf(three_I_ten));
```

**Вопрос:**

Почему в лог пишется: `three_I_ten = 0.0`, когда ожидается `three_I_ten = 0.3` ?

И как сделать, чтобы `three_I_ten = 0.3`?

Comment: потому, что сначала 3 делится 10, и это целочисленное деление. Получается 0, и только потом оно приводится к типу данных `float`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748095/java-double-and-float/748100#748100

Comment: имхо вот правильный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726773/227016